# Qt c++ Increasing integer with pushButton to label

Tags: c++, qt, integer, label

I'm trying to make a simple "Cookie Clicker" game and I'm having trouble with this. When I press the button I want the label to print out "You have mined (VALUE) FSCoins" but the label won't update for some reason. Console shows no errors :(

Here's my code:

mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(int num, int numplus)
{
    num = numplus + 1;
    QString qstr = QString::number(numplus);
    ui->label->setText("You have mined " + qstr + " FSCoins");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've only started working with Qt yesterday and I'm "Sort of" getting the hang of it.

Comment: Have you connected the buttons click signal to your function?

Comment: I don't know Is that done in the header file?

Comment: It's linked. I edited the function and just set this in: ui->label->setText("test"); and the label updated.

Comment: But it just doesn't when I want it to change integers

Comment: the code looks fine itself - you need to provide more code that reproduces your problem. Otherwise we won't be able to help you. I wonder how is your slot triggered. What signal is connected to it? Where is it emited? How does declaration of your slot look?

Answer (score 2):

```
num = numplus + 1;
```

What is the point of this line? `num` is a local variable that is never used. Did you mean to pass it by reference?

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect a SIGNAL to a SLOT, but that function you wrote there does not seem like a SLOT. Somewhere in your code there shall be something like this in your header file:

```
class ...
{
// ...
private slots:
    void onPushButtonClicked();
};
```

and in your source file:

```
// For example in the constructor.
connect( ui->PushButton, SIGNAL( clicked() ), this, SLOT( onPushButtonClicked() ) );

// The implementation of your SLOT.
Class::onPushButtonClicked()
{
    // Your implementation.
    updateLabel( /* Your arguments */ );
}
```

The SLOT function cannot have more arguments than the SIGNAL, so in this case your SLOT cannot have any.

And something else. I prefer this version of creating a QString:

```
QString( "You have mined %1 coins" ).arg( value );
```

I think it's more readable.

So the point is that that you need store that integers somewhere. Maybe in your class as a member variable.

Comment: You shouldn't add personal string creation preferences to your answer, as it's irrelevant. I'm personally glad most people don't touch that awful `printf`-style formatting. Otherwise good answer.

Comment: Sorry about that :(. I wanted to express with the "I prefer", that it's more simple so you don't need to check the spaces at the end and at the front of the string chunks. But I'll try to express myself more accurately.